# GitHub main/master branch

Tags: github

I thought the default head branch was now called "main", but today, I noticed in a new repo, the default branch was still called "master". But when I wanted to rename it, the popup told me that I should use main?
My colleagues did see main as default, so I'm wondering, why don't I? Am I using an old version or something?[image]

Comment: Most projects definitely do not name the default branch `main` as the `master` comes from the [default naming](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) of Git, the underlying software GitHub is just a friendly web GUI for.

Comment: The picture is a screenshot from GitHub, so indeed, it's not default everywhere, but it is on GitHub, that's why I'm wonderring that it's different with me...

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't see what repo is this related to, what you experience is most likely seeing your own **fork** instead of the upstream repository.

If your colleagues see `main` as the master branch and you see `master` on your side, check whether you don't have your username as a prefix in the repo URL or title (that'd be your fork) and instead try to navigate into the upstream repository (the one without your username as a prefix).

Unless you use a GitHub desktop client the version will be the same as your colleagues have because it's being served by the GitHub servers for all the users (kind of, ignoring A/B testing, load-balancing, CDN, etc) and only GitHub can change the version.

If you use the desktop client, always try to update first before opening tickets/questions as issues might have already been resolved

Comment: With the part where I say that my colleagues see 'main', I meant that when they open a new project, their first branch is called 'main', and when I do it, it's called 'master' :)

Comment: @pieter-jangoeman in that case I see only A|B testing/CDN/region as a possible problem whether that is the language or country chosen from the menu or based on IP. Depending on the details you(or your IP, e.g. vpn/proxy) might be in EU while colleagues in US or you might not be a part of the testing group in A/B testing. GitHub has CDN in multiple regions, so it's one of the reasons why it might have happened.